# cannot copy and paste when area size is not the same

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim lastrow&, lastCol&, myarray As Range
lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastCol = Range("XX1").End(xlToLeft).Column
Set myarray = Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, lastCol)
Range("A1", myarray).Select
Selection.Copy
```

So basically, i am trying to get select an array which could vary, I know it starts at A1, but I'm unsure which row and column it will end at. Code above works fine to help copy this array.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
Windows("macrofile.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("MRG").Select
'has to find the last row by itself
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

I am getting an error on the last line `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)`.

> [Error 1004, can't paste because copy area and paste area aren't the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxorp.png)

I have tried different variations including activesheet.paste and xlpastevalues to no avail.

`Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select` selects a single cell in column A to find the last used row and offsets it by 2 rows so I can paste below the existing data. Not sure why error 1004 comes up because replicating selecting an array and pasting it into a single cell in excel runs no errors.

Any help is much appreciated; I am really new to VBA and most of this code came from different sources online.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the source data has no blank rows or columns you can do this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Currentregion.Copy _
  Workbooks("macrofile.xlsm").Sheets("MRG").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2,0)
```

Assuming there's room for the pasted data.